# Getting error in Visual Studio Code 'Cannot find module debug' in Angular

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, terminal, proxy

I am working on Angular project. When hitting `ng build` from terminal in VScode, getting error

```
Z:\CR\Products\AutoReprocess>ng build
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
 throw err;
 ^

Error: Cannot find module 'debug'
 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
 at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
 at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
 at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
 at Object.<anonymous> (Z:CR\Products\AutoReprocess\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:11:15)
 at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
 at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
 at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
 at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
```

How can I solve this issue? My machine don't have any physical drives rather it has virtual drives over the network(I think). I am creating these drive using `pushd` from `cmd` and keeping code in that location, Same path opening in VS Code.

**Edit1**

If I do `npm install` getting below error

```
Z:\CR\Products\AutoReprocess>npm install
npm WARN karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.5.1 requires a peer of jasmine-core@>=3.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: nan@2.14.0 (node_modules\nan):
npm WARN network SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: request to http://registry.nmpjs.org/nan failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.nmpjs.org registry.nmpjs.org:80
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN network SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: request to http://registry.nmpjs.org/fsevents failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.nmpjs.org registry.nmpjs.org:80

npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.nmpjs.org/debug failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.nmpjs.org registry.nmpjs.org:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     Z:\CR\Products\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-07T13_46_00_313Z-debug.log
```

Comment: run `npm install` and see if you get any errors...?

Comment: @ShlokNangia - npm install throwing error. Check my updated question.